# Create File/Folder hierarchy in Apache JCR

Tags: java, rest, jcr

We have a functionality to create a number of folders when user saves the data in CM.
The format would is attached in image:

- ParentFolder

  - ChildFolder1
  - ChildFolder2
  - ChildFolder3
  - File1
  - File2
  - File3
- ParentFolderConfig

  - ChildFolderConfig1
  - ChildFolderConfig2
  - ChildFolderConfig3
  - FileConfig1
  - FileConfig2
  - FileConfig3

These all are created all the times when user creates it. I have found a way to add nodes one by one using addNode(). But to save the time and increase performance I wanted to find out a way in which I create this files and folder temporary in JAVA and save them to JCR in one call and afterwards dispose these temporary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `addNode()` multiple times and saving a the end with `Session.save()` is a common pattern in JCR, it's perfectly fine to create your structure like that.

To make your code simpler you could use a utility class that takes the path of a node that's deep in your hierarchy, and creates intermediate nodes as needed. The [JcrUtils.getOrCreateByPath](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html#getOrCreateByPath%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Session,%20boolean%29) method provided by the Jackrabbit commons module does that.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand,
That was very helpful, but I wanted to know a way to avoid calling addNode() n times and find a way to do it in one turn. But still your help is of great value for me.